# Thousands separators in Ext.form.NumberField

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I want to override some config options of Ext.form.NumberField, but I don't find something like a "thousands separator". Is there a way to define this for NumberFields in Ext?

Or have I had to write my own function to provide this functionality?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? set a different character as the thousands seperator?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do

Comment: Ok, see answer below, it should help I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On closer inspection according to the forums/devs, NumberField doesn't support formatting. Numbercolumn on a grid does.

Their suggestion is to use a TextField and either format the value serverside before displaying it, or to apply a function on say, the 'change' event of a text field to apply the formatting you want, e.g.

```
        <ext:TextField             
            ID="txtField"            
            runat="server"             
            FieldLabel="My Label"            
            AllowBlank="false"             
            ReadOnly="true">             
            <Listeners>                 
                <Change Handler="this.setValue(Ext.util.Format.number(newValue.replace(/[\,\.]/g, ''), '0.000/i'));" />             
            </Listeners>         
        </ext:TextField>
```

I would assume you'd need to tweak things a little to ensure your value was displayed as you'd like but there should be something you fit in the Ext.util.Format.number patterns listed here:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/output/Ext.util.Format.html#Ext.util.Format-number

Comment: You said, that NumberField doesn't support formatting. I guess, that's not correct. There is a config option called "decimalSeparator". Because of that, I've expected that there has to be something like a "thousandSeparator" option. But thanks for your answer. I will evaluate your suggest.

Comment: a property is not formatting, on a NumberColumn you can explicitely define format: "0.00" for example and that formatting will be applied. NumberField does not support this, which is why you need to apply a function to a text field.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use this override

[Ext.override.ThousandSeparatorNumberField](https://github.com/omids20m/Ext.override.ThousandSeparatorNumberField)