# Sencha extjs setValue string to numberfield

Tags: javascript, string, extjs, extjs6, extjs6-modern

I need to use numberfield for user input number. When I set string '123,555' it shows only 123 to numberfield. But if I use textfield, it works as expected. I use this for thousand separation.

```
xtype: 'numberfield',
itemId: 'payment1',
cls : 'txtAlignRight',
flex : 4,
value:'0',
autoComplete: false,
autoCorrect: false,
clearIcon: false,
originalValue: true,
required: true,
maxLength: 15,

//------------------
num.setValue('123,555')
//result = 123
```

Is there any solutions to do it? Thanks in advance.
Note: I use sencha extjs 6 modern.

Comment: @DavidR I guess he is working on thousand separator.

Comment: @Phon , NumberField doesn't support formatting and in this case you have to use `textfield`. A similar question I found here please check for solution.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413188/thousands-separators-in-ext-form-numberfield

Comment: @DavidR Ya, hehe, Actually I Was preparing a fiddle for you. [Future Reference ] https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1imq

Comment: @UDID Ha haa :D

Comment: You would need to manually convert it to a number first, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405178/parsing-numbers-with-a-comma-decimal-separator-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setRawValue()` method of the numberfield. This will bypass all conversion and validation that you get when using setValue().

Documentation:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Number-method-setRawValue

Example:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/1iuu/preview

This will merely set the value and will not work to increment / decrement using buttons the way this is coded now.

Comment: I use sencha extjs 6 modern. setRawValue() is not working.

Comment: My mistake; I missed the note at the end of your question. I recommend adding the 'extjs6-modern' or 'extjs6' tag to your question.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question. Have you got any idea with this?

Comment: Do you need the comma to display in the numberfield? Or are you only trying to set the value of the numberfield using a string formatted like a number? If you need the comma to show up in the in the field then I think your only option is to use a textfield with some validation. If you're just trying to set the field with a string formatted like a number then I have a solution that will work.

Comment: Actually, I want the comma to display in the numberfield. anw, I fixed it alr.

Answer (score 1):

TO change which chars are allowed. You might wanna change these properties
The way these properties work is [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/src/Number.js-2.html)

1. autoStripChars: false,
2. disableKeyFilter: true
3. stripCharsRe:     false
4. maskRe:           false

Sounds like you're needing to add [Formatting](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.util.Format) to a number field.

here is an [override](https://github.com/omids20m/Ext.override.ThousandSeparatorNumberField) that adds the **useThousandSeperator** to a  numberfield

[image: Ext.util.Format]

Answer (score 0):

Number filed allow only digit (0-9 and '.') 
And if you still want to allow ',' in numberfield then you can set by following propertie.

baseChars :'0123456789,'